# Cannot open log for source 'blah'. You may not have write access

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, windows-event-log

I'm attempting to write to a custom event log .... but I get the error:

```
 Win32Exception Access Is Denied
 Cannot open log for source 'blah'. You may not have write access.
```

I've trawled the net.. followed varions links and to date the best one I've come across is 
[this MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028427). It's not as clear as it could be though.

This is a 2008 R2 development server.
I've added the following `REG_SZ` key `CustomSD` with a value of 
`O:BAG:SYD:(A;; 0x7;;;AN)(A;; 0x7;;;SY)(A;; 0x7;;;BA)(A;; 0x7;;;SO)(A;; 0x7;;;IU)(A;; 0x7;;;SU)` to registry folders "eventlog" and my sub folders.

I've also allowed everyone full access to the physical event log (.evtx file)... but all to no avail.

I think I'm giving Read Write and Clear access to the various account types (SY=System etc,).

My website which fails is running under the default IISAPPPool account.